# There is something strange with recursive subquery factoring in Oracle about date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table called trans_info.

| date_d | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 | 3 |
| 2016-01-02 | 2 |
| 2016-01-03 | 1 |
| 2016-01-05 | 4 |

when I execute the sql

```
with m1 as (
  select 
  ti.date_d,ti.weight,row_number() over(order by ti.date_d) rn
  from trans_info ti 
),m2(date_d,weight,rn,start_date) as (
  select
  date_d,weight,rn,date_d as start_date
  from m1 where rn=1
  union all
  select
  a.date_d,a.weight,a.rn,
  case when b.start_date+4 <= a.date_d then a.date_d else b.start_date end
  from m1 a,m2 b where b.rn+1=a.rn
)

select * from m2
```

The result is

| date_d | weight | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 | 3 | 2016-01-01 |
| 2016-01-02 | 2 | 2016-01-02 |
| 2016-01-03 | 1 | 2016-01-03 |
| 2016-01-05 | 4 | 2016-01-05 |

However, when I change the sql to the following

```
with m1 as (
  select 
  ti.date_d,ti.weight,row_number() over(order by ti.date_d) rn
  from trans_info ti 
),m2(date_d,weight,rn,start_date) as (
  select
  date_d,weight,rn,date_d as start_date
  from m1 where rn=1
  union all
  select
  a.date_d,a.weight,a.rn,
  case when 4 <= a.date_d-b.start_date then a.date_d else b.start_date end
  from m1 a,m2 b where b.rn+1=a.rn
)

select * from m2
```

The result is

| date_d | weight | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 | 3 | 2016-01-01 |
| 2016-01-02 | 2 | 2016-01-01 |
| 2016-01-03 | 1 | 2016-01-01 |
| 2016-01-05 | 4 | 2016-01-05 |

The only difference between two sqls is the comparison of date.

```
b.start_date+4 <= a.date_d

4 <= a.date_d-b.start_date
```

It is really strange. Why?. I execute the sql on Oracle  11g.

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type that is composed of 7-bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

Client applications (i.e. SQL Developer, SQL*Plus, etc.) typically choose to display a `DATE` not in its raw binary form but as a human readable string. Some client applications may default to not showing the all the components of a date; that does not mean that those components do not exist, only that they aren't being displayed to you.

To show the entire value you can use:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_d, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM trans_info;
```

Or, in SQL Developer or SQL*Plus, you can change the default display format for dates using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

---

As for your data, if your dates have midnight time components then both queries output exactly the same values.

If your dates have non-midnight time components then you get different behaviour, as you are seeing.

```
CREATE TABLE trans_info (date_d, weight) AS
SELECT DATE '2016-01-01', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-01-02', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-01-03', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-01-05', 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Then both of your queries output:

| DATE_D | WEIGHT | RN | START_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 1 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2016-01-02 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2016-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | 3 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2016-01-05 00:00:00 | 4 | 4 | 2016-01-05 00:00:00 |

If you then do:

```sql
UPDATE trans_info
SET date_d = date_d + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND
WHERE weight = 3;
```

Then the output changes to:

| DATE_D | WEIGHT | RN | START_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 23:59:59 | 3 | 1 | 2016-01-01 23:59:59 |
| 2016-01-02 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 | 2016-01-01 23:59:59 |
| 2016-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | 3 | 2016-01-01 23:59:59 |
| 2016-01-05 00:00:00 | 4 | 4 | 2016-01-01 23:59:59 |

If you change the query to:

```
with m1 as (
  select TRUNC(date_d) AS date_d,
         weight,
         row_number() over(order by TRUNC(date_d)) rn
  from   trans_info
),
m2(date_d,weight,rn,start_date) as (
  select date_d,
         weight,
         rn,
         date_d as start_date
  from   m1
  where  rn=1
  union all
  select a.date_d,
         a.weight,a.rn,
         case
         when 4 <= a.date_d-b.start_date
         then a.date_d
         else b.start_date
         end
  from   m1 a,
         m2 b
  where  b.rn+1=a.rn
)
select * from m2
```

Then the original behaviour is restored:

| DATE_D | WEIGHT | RN | START_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 1 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2016-01-02 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2016-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | 3 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2016-01-05 00:00:00 | 4 | 4 | 2016-01-05 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7sjNcRN2)

Answer (score 0):

> I execute the sql on Oracle 11g

Recursive subquery factoring was [new in 11g release 2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/wnsql.htm#insertedID2), and had quite a lot of bugs. You seem to be experiencing one of them. It's hard to know which one; it could be 11840579 as that is specifically about dates, but it could be something else, or an unpublished bug.

As @MTO's fiddle shows your queries get the same results in 21c, but [in an unpatched 11.2.0.1 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yflX_kTT) the first two queries get exactly the result you did. (Also notice that the fourth query gets an error, which seems to be another bug in that base version).

Assuming you are also still on the base version you could potentially still patch up to 11.2.0.4, if you have a support contract, or upgrade to a more recent - and supported - version where this is fixed.

Otherwise you'll just need to careful to check your results and modify your queries to work around any oddities you encounter.